# javascript add html tag to all input required fields

Tags: javascript, html

I have the next input fields in simple form:

```
var login = document.getElementById("login");
var password = document.getElementById("password");
var name = document.getElementById("name");
var email = document.getElementById("email");
```

What I want to do is when *submit* button is pushed, add **span** element before **input** fields.

```
var spanTag = document.createElement("span");
```

`insertBefore` works only for the last element.

**FULL code:**

```
<script>
    function addRequiredAttribute(buttonName) {
        var login = document.getElementById("login");
        var password = document.getElementById("password");
        var name = document.getElementById("name");
        var email = document.getElementById("email");

        var spanTag = document.createElement("span");
        spanTag.className ="required";

        if(buttonName === "add") {
            login.setAttribute("required","required");
            login.parentNode.insertBefore(spanTag, login);
            password.setAttribute("required","required");
            password.parentNode.insertBefore(spanTag, password);
            name.setAttribute("required","required");
            name.parentNode.insertBefore(spanTag, name);
            email.setAttribute("required","required");
            email.parentNode.insertBefore(spanTag, email);
        } else {
            login.setAttribute("required","required");
            login.parentNode.insertBefore(spanTag, login);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Add rest of code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't insert the same span before all the fields, you should clone it using `spanTag.cloneNode(true)` for every input field.

```js
function addRequiredAttribute(buttonName) {
  var login = document.getElementById("login");
  var password = document.getElementById("password");
  var name = document.getElementById("name");
  var email = document.getElementById("email");

  var spanTag = document.createElement("span");
  spanTag.className ="required";
  spanTag.textContent ="example span text ";

  if(buttonName === "add") {
    login.setAttribute("required","required");
    login.parentNode.insertBefore(spanTag.cloneNode(true), login);
    password.setAttribute("required","required");
    password.parentNode.insertBefore(spanTag.cloneNode(true), password);
    name.setAttribute("required","required");
    name.parentNode.insertBefore(spanTag.cloneNode(true), name);
    email.setAttribute("required","required");
    email.parentNode.insertBefore(spanTag.cloneNode(true), email);
  } else {
    login.setAttribute("required","required");
    login.parentNode.insertBefore(spanTag, login);
  }
}

addRequiredAttribute('add');
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="login" /><br/>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="password" id="password" /><br/>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="name" /><br/>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="email" id="email" />
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

@Zakaria's answer is perfect, but instead of creating `span` tags individually, you can either nests such inputs inside a div or add a class specific to them.

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/Lmtoqzhg/2/).

#### Snippet

```
inputs[i].required;
```

#### Sample Code

```js
(function () {
    var form = document.getElementsByClassName("form");
    var inputs = form[0].getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.id = "span_" + i;
        span.textContent = "Span " + i + " Required: " + inputs[i].required;
        inputs[i].parentNode.insertBefore(span, inputs[i]);
    }
})()
```

```css
span {
    padding:5px;
    background:#ddd;
    margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
    <input type="text" id="login" required>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="password">
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="name" required>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="email">
    <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: How to collect all input but with required tag set only?